# Waiting Queue - creating room for 2 clients and redirecting those two clients to same URL

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, flask

The brief outline of my problem is as follows:

2 clients can choose to play online:

[image: 2 clients can choose to play online]

By this I mean:

To join a global waiting queue:

[image: To join a global waiting queue.]

- Both clients emit to the server every 1s 'join_random()' - which means just see if there is a room available for me.

```
function joinRandomGame() {
    socket.emit('join_random', 
                { game    : window.roomVariables.game, 
                  user_id : window.roomVariables.user_id });

setInterval(joinRandomGame, 1000); }
```

- the function join_random checks if there is another player waiting in the queue
- if there is: both clients are redirected to the new url through the play_game socket

  ```
   from threading import Lock

    userQueueLock = Lock()
    userQueue = dequeue()

    @socketio.on('join_random')
    def handle_join_random(data):
        game = data['game']
        user_id = data['user_id']
        print(userQueue)

        with userQueueLock:
            if user_id not in userQueue:
                userQueue.append(user_id)


            if len(userQueue) >= 2:
                player1 = userQueue.popleft()
                player2 = userQueue.popleft()

                room_id = generate_random_key()              
                room = Room(
                    id=room_id,
                    users=[player1, player2],    
                    points=[0, 0],
                    ...
                )

                db.session.add(room)
                db.session.commit()

                #Threading error
                join_room(room_id, sid=player1) 
                join_room(room_id, sid=player2)

                emit('play_game',{'game': game, 'room_id': room_id}, room=room_id)
  ```

When we reach the point where both clients are in the queue and join_room is called for both clients I am met with the following threading error

```
    deque(['user_1709895093301', 'user_1707675752654'])
Exception in thread Thread-104 (_handle_event_internal):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 586, in _handle_event_internal
    r = server._trigger_event(data[0], namespace, sid, *data[1:])
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 611, in _trigger_event
    return handler(*args)
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 282, in _handler
    return self._handle_event(handler, message, namespace, sid,
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 827, in _handle_event
    ret = handler(*args)
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/socketio_events.py", line 125, in handle_join_random
    join_room(room_id, sid=player1)
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 1035, in join_room
    socketio.server.enter_room(sid, room, namespace=namespace)
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/server.py", line 282, in enter_room
    self.manager.enter_room(sid, namespace, room)
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/manager.py", line 71, in enter_room
    return self.basic_enter_room(sid, namespace, room, eio_sid=eio_sid)
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/socketio/base_manager.py", line 112, in basic_enter_room
    eio_sid = self.rooms[namespace][None][sid]
  File "/home/taylor/Desktop/Projects/web_dev/Projects/Flask/Tic-Tac-Toe-Web/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bidict/_base.py", line 523, in __getitem__
    return self._fwdm[key]
KeyError: 'user_1709895093301'
```

Comment: Codebase: https://github.com/LunaTMT/GameHub-Web

Comment: Show output and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: This is what you expect, right?  You get one player.  He gets pushed on the queue, but no one can play yet.  You get a second player.  Now the queue had two items, and you remove them both.  You won't get called until there's a new first player.

Comment: This does look like a locking problem. Maybe you could use `threading.Lock` to ensure that everything from `userQueue.append(user_id)` up to `userQueue.popleft()` is never executed in parallel by multiple users.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the `room_created` and `room_joined` events have both `player1` and `player2` IDs? Instead of just `player2`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes that is essentially what I want. When there are two player waiting in the queue, they should be assigned their room and a redirect should occur. However, the latter part does not occur due to threading issues.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek The room_created and room_joined emits are essentially just for debugging on the client side. I've gotten rid of it from the post because it has nothing to do with the problem. I am going to try your first solution.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek I've updated the code in the post with a threading lock but am still having the same problem.

Comment: If i do not pop them and just use index reference 0 and 1 I am met with the following error:  `deque(['user_1707675752654', 'user_1709895093301'])

Exception in thread Thread-25 (_handle_event_internal):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs
...
    return self._fwdm[key]
KeyError: 'user_1707675752654'`

Comment: Just to make sure. The original problem is that there is always either 1 or 2 players in the queue when printed out, and never 0? If yes, then it lies purely in the fact that `print(userQueue)` happens **after** `append(user_id)`, but **before** `popleft()`... so the queue behaves as you would expect, and it's just the placement of `print` that makes it looks wrong.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek Oh I see why now. So now the initial problem switches to why I can't join_room for both players and am recieving a threading error. Thanks